# Google Satellite on QGIS 3.16 does not work

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to visualize on QGIS 3.16 Google Satellite using the URL:

[http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](http://www.google.cn/maps/vt?lyrs=s@189&gl=cn&x=%7Bx%7D&y=%7By%7D&z=%7Bz%7D)

But after using this URL, I cant not visualize Google Satellite.

Should I modify other data from QGIS?

Comment: "It does not work" is not a very useful problem statement. Please [Edit] the question to detail errors or actual behavior.

Comment: [https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}](https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z})

Comment: For me your link is working as desired. So the problem comes not with this layer.

Answer (score 2):

If you **copy/paste** following lines in Python Console of QGIS, you can get access to Google Satellite.

```
import requests

service_uri = "type=xyz&zmin=0&zmax=21&url=https://" + requests.utils.quote("mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}")

iface.addRasterLayer(service_uri, "Google Sat", "wms")
```

This is the result:

[image]

After **Zoom In** arbitrarily in point (-8221396.7,4972587.6), you can get something similar to this.

[image]

Comment: It does not work.
If I run the code in python console, Goolge satellite appears in the active layers, but I can not visualize it.

Comment: Is there some problem with chinese internet restrictions? I don't know, but you mentioned google.cn and the WMS request goes to .com, maybe something gets blocked?